# Permission denied on /proc/net/ and /sys/devices/system

Tags: permissions, proc

We are deploying the node_exporter on all of our servers to monitor resources. Some servers are spamming the logs with the following :

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq: permission denied
```

or

```
could not get ARP entries: open /proc/net/arp: permission denied
```

On these servers I am also getting permission denied when I want to cat /proc/net/arp (as an example) as a regular user. When executing this as sudo, I am able to see the contents. This however is only the case on some of our servers, most of them are able to read the contents of proc and sys as a regular user. The read/write permission and owners of these files are exactly the same on both servers (working and not-working):

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 23 14:04 arp
```

/proc is mounted the same way on both servers as well (in /etc/fstab).
I tried unmounting and remounting /proc on the failing servers but no luck. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify if there isn't any SELinux policy in place preventing the regular user from reading these files.

[This](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/linux/servers/587-find-if-permission-denied-error-is-caused-by-selinux) post can help you to verify if it is the case.

Comment: Thanks. I use Ubuntu; these use AppArmor instead. However, on the failing servers aa-status shows that the apparmor module is not loaded. Some of the working servers have apparmor enabled. So it doesn't look like this is the issue.